# Как составить регулярное выражение для двух строк?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеется две строки: '7-9.05.2022' и '19.12.2021'. Необходимо в первой строке удалить значение между тире(-) и точкой(.), но чтобы вторая строка тоже соответствовала данному регулярному выражению.

Comment: соответствие и удаление это разные вещи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если уж цель удалить кусок `-9`, то проще так:

```js
result = string.replace(/-\d+/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем так как предполагалось, но поступил следующим образом:

```
result = /(^\d*).*?(\.\d*\.\d*)/.exec(string)
result[1]+result[2]
```